# How to convert this code to java8 lambda

Tags: java, java-8

I've just started working with Java 8 and I'm struggling with this code snippet:

```
paramsValues[idx++] = new ReplyMessage<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void reply(JsonObject reply) {
        message.reply(reply);
    }
};
```

How to convert this to Lambda style?

Comment: Is there any online converter tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ReplyMessage` is a *functional interface*, you could do

```
paramsValues[idx++] = reply -> message.reply(reply);
```

Here's a full example with stub implementations of the other classes in your question:

```
// Stub classes
class JsonObject { }

@FunctionalInterface
interface ReplyMessage<T> {
    void reply(T jo);
}

class LambdaDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Dummy variables
        ReplyMessage<JsonObject> message = new ReplyMessage<JsonObject>() {
            public void reply(JsonObject jo) {}
        };
        ReplyMessage[] paramsValues = new ReplyMessage[5];
        int idx = 0;

        // Your code, lambdafied
        paramsValues[idx++] = reply -> message.reply(reply);

        // Or,
        // paramsValues[idx++] = message::reply;

        // But then you could perhaps do with just ...
        // paramsValues[idx++] = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interface should have a generic type (`interface ReplyMessage<T>`)

Comment: @LouisWasserman, right. I just wanted to be a bit more verbose for educational purposes.

Comment: In my case 'paramsValues' is defined as follow:

Object[] paramsValues = new Object[params.length];

so I get a compilation error:
"The target type of this expression must be a functional interface"

Comment: Try this: `paramsValues[idx++] = (ReplyMessage<?>) ((JsonObject reply) -> message.reply(reply));`

Comment: Why not `paramsValues[idx++] = (ReplyMessage<JsonObject>) reply -> message.reply(reply);` as it’s only the target type that has to be included; there is no reason to make anything else more complicated compared to the original solution.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda expressions are only possible with **[Functional Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html)** (Interfaces with only one method, such as *Runnable* or `ActionEvent`)

If `ReplyMessage` is a functional interface, you can do:

```
paramsValues[idx++] = reply -> message.reply(reply);
```

Lambda expressions are formed in this pattern: parameters that the method should take, then `->` then the method body

Here is the code of how `ReplyMessage` interface should look like:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface ReplyMessage<T> {
    void reply(T jo);
}
```

For more information, consider reading [**this**](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html).

Comment: The usage of `@FunctionalInterface` is optional. Also the restriction is not "only one method" but one abstract method. That's a rather big difference. I wonder what you mean by "take parameters". A function has parameters and takes arguments, if you meant that.

Answer (score 0):

```
paramValues[idx++] = reply -> message.reply(reply);
```

Or

```
paramValues[idx++] = reply -> {
    return message.reply(reply);
}
```

It will work as long as `ReplyMessage<JsonObject>` is functional interface and paramValues is of type `ReplyMessage<JsonObject>`.